# How to looping the variable on php

Tags: php

i have problem on my comment list in my forum website php
please help
i trying to looping all the user comment,
but it just appear 1 or fail looping that show all same comment in many number.

```
<?php
include 'connection.php'; 
        echo '<table border="1" bgcolor="#FBFBEF" width="100%" height="20"><tr>';
        echo '<td width="80%" height="20"><strong>Thread :';
        $query="select title from topic where topic_id=".$_REQUEST['topic'];
        $result=mysql_query($query);
        $row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
        echo $row['title'];
    if($row){
      do{   
    echo'</strong></td><td  align="center" valign="top"><strong><?php ';
      $query2="select * from comment where topic_id=".$_REQUEST['topic'];
      $result2=mysql_query($query2);
      $row2=mysql_fetch_array($result2);
      echo $row2['post_date'];
      echo '</strong></td></tr></table>';
    echo '<table border="1" bgcolor="#FBFBEF" width="100%" height="20"><tr><td align="center" valign="top" height="20"><strong> Post By :<strong></td><td width="85%" ><strong>';
        echo $row['title'];
        echo'</strong></td></tr>';
    echo '<tr><td align="center" valign="top"><strong>';
            $query3="select * from user_login where email='".$row2['post_by_user']."'";
            $result3=mysql_query($query3);
            $row3=mysql_fetch_array($result3);
            echo '<br>'.$row3['first_name'].' '.$row3['last_name'];

        echo '</strong></td><td align="left" valign="top" height=200>';
      //displaying list comment
    echo '<p>'.$row2['description'].'</p><hr>';
     }while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result2));
      }
      ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

why is the looping failed ?

Comment: `$row=mysql_fetch_array($result2)` is not a comparison?

Comment: you are looping in wrong place with non-related variables. Side Note: you are highly prone to SOL-injection and using depreciated mysql_* functions

Comment: can u fix it please ? :d

Answer (score 0):

I have re-arranged your loop. The first thing wrong was `while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result2))` because you are using `$row2` in that loop and changing `$row` won't help.

```
<?php
include 'connection.php';
echo '<table border="1" bgcolor="#FBFBEF" width="100%" height="20"><tr>';
echo '<td width="80%" height="20"><strong>Thread :';
$query = "select title from topic where topic_id=" . $_REQUEST['topic'];
$result = mysql_query($query);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
echo $row['title'];
if ($row) {
    echo '</strong></td><td  align="center" valign="top"><strong><?php ';
    $query2 = "select * from comment where topic_id=" . $_REQUEST['topic'];
    $result2 = mysql_query($query2);
    while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2)) {
        echo $row2['post_date'];
        echo '</strong></td></tr></table>';
        echo '<table border="1" bgcolor="#FBFBEF" width="100%" height="20"><tr><td align="center" valign="top" height="20"><strong> Post By :<strong></td><td width="85%" ><strong>';
        echo $row['title'];
        echo '</strong></td></tr>';
        echo '<tr><td align="center" valign="top"><strong>';
        $query3 = "select * from user_login where email='" . $row2['post_by_user'] . "'";
        $result3 = mysql_query($query3);
        $row3 = mysql_fetch_array($result3);
        echo '<br>' . $row3['first_name'] . ' ' . $row3['last_name'];

        echo '</strong></td><td align="left" valign="top" height=200>';
        //displaying list comment
        echo '<p>' . $row2['description'] . '</p><hr>';
    }
}
?>
</td>
</tr>
```

**Very Important:** You are highly prone to SQL-Injection. Please at-least sanitize your input before feeding to SQL. Also you are using depreciated mysql_* functions. Instead, use the [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension.

Side note: errors are inversely proportional to readability of your code. and maintainability is proportional to square of readability.

Edit: If you want `echo $row2['post_date']` only once for the loop you can use the loop like this. This will print `post_date` of the first row only.

```
if ($row) {
    echo '</strong></td><td  align="center" valign="top"><strong><?php ';
    $query2 = "select * from comment where topic_id=" . $_REQUEST['topic'];
    $result2 = mysql_query($query2);
    $row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2);
    if ($row2) {
        echo $row2['post_date'];
        do {
            echo '</strong></td></tr></table>';
            echo '<table border="1" bgcolor="#FBFBEF" width="100%" height="20"><tr><td align="center" valign="top" height="20"><strong> Post By :<strong></td><td width="85%" ><strong>';
            echo $row['title'];
            echo '</strong></td></tr>';
            echo '<tr><td align="center" valign="top"><strong>';
            $query3 = "select * from user_login where email='" . $row2['post_by_user'] . "'";
            $result3 = mysql_query($query3);
            $row3 = mysql_fetch_array($result3);
            echo '<br>' . $row3['first_name'] . ' ' . $row3['last_name'];

            echo '</strong></td><td align="left" valign="top" height=200>';
            //displaying list comment
            echo '<p>' . $row2['description'] . '</p><hr>';
        } while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2));
    }
}
```

Comment: thx for the answer, but the date is still on the loop, how can put the date outside of the loop ? echo $row2['post_date']; this code above  while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2)) { ??

Comment: do you mean `echo $row2['post_date']` only once for the loop?

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the errors in your code you also have several [SQL injection vulnerabilities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) and unescaped output vulnerabilities.

1. Your `$result2` variable is being assigned **inside** you do/while loop. That means that at each iteration of the loop it is being overwritten. This will never result in more than one iteration's worth of output.
2. You need to spend some time becoming more familiar with PHP, databases (in your case MySQL), and the nature of [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Here is your code, reworked to address your logic problem and the SQL injection vulnerabilities. You'll need to take some time to understand and then address the [problems with outputting unescaped user input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129677/whats-the-best-method-for-sanitizing-user-input-with-php).

```
  <?php

  // You will need to define $dbConnection per the MySQLi API.
  // http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php
  include 'connection.php';

  echo '<table border="1" bgcolor="#FBFBEF" width="100%" height="20"><tr>';
  echo '<td width="80%" height="20"><strong>Thread :';

  $stmt = $dbConnection->prepare('select title from topic where topic_id = ?');
  $stmt->bind_param('s', $_REQUEST['topic']);

  $result = $stmt->get_result();
  $row = $result->fetch_assoc();

  echo $row['title'];

  if ($row)
  {
    $query2 = "select * from comment where topic_id=".$_REQUEST['topic'];

    $stmt2 = $dbConnection->prepare('select * from comment where topic_id = ?');
    $stmt2->bind_param('s', $_REQUEST['topic']);

    $result2 = $stmt->get_result();

    while ($row2 = $result2->fetch_assoc())
    {
      echo'</strong></td><td  align="center" valign="top"><strong><?php ';
      echo $row2['post_date'];
      echo '</strong></td></tr></table>';
      echo '<table border="1" bgcolor="#FBFBEF" width="100%" height="20"><tr><td align="center" valign="top" height="20"><strong> Post By :<strong></td><td width="85%" ><strong>';
      echo $row['title'];
      echo'</strong></td></tr>';
      echo '<tr><td align="center" valign="top"><strong>';

      $stmt3 = $dbConnection->prepare('select * from user_login where email = ?');
      $stmt3->bind_param('s', $row2['post_by_user']);

      $row3 = $result3->fetch_assoc()

      echo '<br>' . $row3['first_name'] . ' ' . $row3['last_name'];

      echo '</strong></td><td align="left" valign="top" height=200>';
      //displaying list comment
      echo '<p>'.$row2['description'].'</p><hr>';
    }
  }
  ?>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: the sir for the code, but i cant understand most the code u change, still a newbie,maybe i have to learn more here .thx!

Answer (score 0):

You have used $result2 in while loop condition, change it to $result to get things working

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result));
```